# We are not able to access data from custom object in apex class

Tags: apex

I want to access the id of property contact relationship id from property contact junction object I am using SOQL query inside the apex class static method and I'm calling the static method from the apex controller. but I am not getting the Id from the property contact junction.

below is the code for controller -

```
    handleContactUpdated : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.helperMethod(component, event); 
        var PropertyAssigned = component.get("v.ContactRecord.Property_Cont__c") 
        var PropertyChoosed = component.get("v.recordId") 
        var ContactChoosed=component.get("v.contactId")
        alert("Property"+PropertyChoosed);
        alert("Contact"+ContactChoosed);
        if(PropertyChoosed != null &&  PropertyChoosed != undefined )
        {
            if(ContactChoosed !=null &&  ContactChoosed != undefined)
            {

                            alert("Inside if----");
            var pcjId = fetchPCJId.getPidCid(PropertyChoosed,ContactChoosed);


            alert("PCJ Id"+pcjId);
            if(pcjId!=null)
            {
                component.set("v.contactErrMessage","");

                component.set("v.isValidContact",true)
            }
            else
            {
                component.set("v.contactErrMessage","This Contact is not assigned to the Property.");

            }
        }
         }

        if(PropertyChoosed != null && PropertyChoosed != undefined){
        component.set("v.contactErrMessage","");

                component.set("v.isValidContact",true)
}

        else{
             component.set("v.propertyErrMessage","Please select the property first.");
        }


    },
```

Below is the code for apex class -

```
public class fetchPCJId {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)


    Public static Property_Contact_Junction__c getPidCid(Id propertyId, Id cId) 
    {
 Property_Contact_Junction__c pIdcId =[select Id from Property_Contact_Junction__c where Property_Name__c =: propertyId  AND Contact_Name__c =: cId];
return pIdcId;

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked field-level security for those fields already?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call Apex method DIRECTLY from lightning javascript. You need to follow [certain lightning APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm). You need to set `fetchPCJId` as ***controller*** in `<aura:component>`

```
if(PropertyChoosed != null &&  PropertyChoosed != undefined )
    {
        if(ContactChoosed !=null &&  ContactChoosed != undefined)
        {
            var pcjId = fetchPCJId.getPidCid(PropertyChoosed,ContactChoosed);
            var action = cmp.get("c.getPidCid");
            action.setParams({ 
                propertyId : PropertyChoosed,
                cId : ContactChoosed
            });

            // Create a callback that is executed after 
            // the server-side action returns
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
                if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                    // Alert the user with the value returned 
                    // from the server
                    let pcjId = response.getReturnValue();
                    alert("From server: " + pcjId);

                    if(pcjId!=null)
                    {
                        component.set("v.contactErrMessage","");

                        component.set("v.isValidContact",true)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        component.set("v.contactErrMessage","This Contact is not assigned to the Property.");
                    }
                }
                else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    // do something
                }
                    else if (state === "ERROR") {
                        var errors = response.getError();
                        if (errors) {
                            if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                                console.log("Error message: " + 
                                            errors[0].message);
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log("Unknown error");
                        }
                    }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    }
```